# How to I make a simple window that I can render to?

Tags: java, swing, vector, 2d, transformation

I've just finished a 2D vector/transformation library that I want to use on a simple example. I have a main loop that runs efficiently and update/render methods. I've always tried to understand what people are talking about when they use Java2D or jPanels or jFrames, but none of it makes sense to me.

I've made some 2D examples before, but it is using a jFrame with a Threaded canvas that I made when following a youtube tutorial. Its problem is that it is basically an integer array that allows for individual pixel setting and you can only use integers as positions, not floats like my library uses.

so my question is: how would I go about making a simple opening/closing window, that I can draw a sprite (should sprites just be some sort of slickUtil loaded thing, or will I have to load in individual pixels as I did before?) to, and that accepts float values for Cartesian coordinates with the origin at the centre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive a class from JComponent and override the paintComponent method. It gets passed a Graphics object that can be cast into a Graphics2D object. The latter one has support for changing the coordinate system.

For drawing sprites: Loading individual pixels in a loop is very slow. There is a drawImage method in Graphics2D that supports everything you need for blitting sprites.

Here's an example to setup the Graphics2D object with a centered origin in a self-contained example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Draw2D extends JFrame {
    public Draw2D() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new DrawPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Draw2D drawing = new Draw2D();
        drawing.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DrawPane extends JComponent {
    public DrawPane() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // use anti-aliasing for smooth lines
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // move origin to center
        g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        // scale as you need. Using negative y so that y points upward
        // note that non-square window sizes will cause a different aspect ratio,
        // you probably want to use Math.min(width, height) or something
        g2.scale(getWidth() / 2, -getHeight() / 2);

        // set color and thickness
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f));

        // draw coordinate lines
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(-1f, 0f, 1.0f, 0f));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        // draw a vector
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(0f, 0f, 0.25f, 0.25f));
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, this whole idea of Graphics objects, and JPanels and so on I don't have a clue. I can read the online documentation, try it out, copy it out, etc all I want and I never get anything to show up.

Comment: if you are willing to make an example I would greatly appreciate it, do I need to upload my source code, or did I explain what I have clearly enough?

Comment: Added the example. Suits your need?

Comment: This is excellent, so now it's question time :) so in my render method I just refer to this to continually draw and add to the screen? Can I add buffered images by draw(), like you did with the line?

Comment: I updated the example to add more lines and turn on anti aliasing for smoother lines. For adding more stuff, you could create a list of Shape objects that are painted in the paintComponent method using a loop. You can change the list outside of the paint method and call repaint() to update the drawing.

Comment: Anyway, thank you SO MUCH fpw, it's all good stuff, and I look forward to implementing it!